# How to run DDO on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, dungeons-and-dragons-online

I am trying to run DDO on Ubuntu 14.04. I would rather not use a VM. Is there an up to date tutorial?

Comment: Does the game support Linux natively? If not, you'll have to use something else such as a VM or Wine (or it's gaming oriented off-shoots such as Crossover or Cedega).

Comment: What does LotRO have to do with this?

Comment: @PrivatePansy LotRO is a sister game of DDO both developed by Turbine Inc.  What applies to one for this kind of thing usually applies to the other.

Comment: Rather than ask us for a guide, you'll be better served if you give it a shot, and if you get stuck, asking us about where you're stuck.  Guides tend to be rather general things, which don't work well here on Arqade.

Answer (score 2):

"DDO" is not an abbreviation I'm familiar with, but I'm assuming you're referring to **Dungeons & Dragons Online: Eberron Unlimited**.  If so, you're in luck.

[WineHQ has a step-by-step tutorial for it, and DDO on Wine is rated platinum.](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2910)

I strongly recommend visiting WineHQ and poking around, and if you should attempt this, the method that uses PlayOnLinux is normally the easier one by far.

Good luck!

---

Link copied here to guard against link rot:

> Standard DDO Wine installation
>
> First, you need Wine and/or PlayOnLinux installed.
>
> Check your distribution's package manager - you want either the latest
>   stable (currently 1.6.2) or the latest testing (currently 1.7.22, but
>   changes frequently) wine.  If you're going to use PlayOnLinux, just
>   grab 1.6.2 since it's required for PlayOnLinux to be installed - If
>   you want a newer version you can install it within PoL itself.
>
> As for PlayOnLinux, the newest version is 4.2.4, but any reasonably
>   recent version should be fine - check your package manager and install
>   it from there first. If it's not available from your package manager,
>   you can download it from playonlinux.com. Make sure you follow the
>   instructions there which are appropriate for your distrubution type.
>
> For complete Wine installation on systems such as Arch/Manjaro 64bit
>   make sure you also install these packages:
>
> Samba lib32-ncurses lib32-mpg123 lib32-libldap lib32-openal
>
> Nvidia users might also need/want: lib32-opengl-nvidia
>   lib32-opencl-nvidia
>
> If you're using wine without PlayOnLinux, you will also need
>   winetricks (check your package manager, most distros have it available
>   by default, or get it from http://winetricks.org/winetricks, mark it
>   executable (chmod +x winetricks) and move it to /usr/local/bin (sudo
>   mv winetricks /usr/local/bin) ).
>
> Grab the installer from http://www.ddo.com/en/game/download  (Get the
>   one that under "On PC" that says "Download then Play" - the "Play
>   Instantly" version uses HappyCloud, which DOES NOT WORK). Installing
>   the game:
>
> Wine users (if you use PlayOnLinux instead, see below) - Open a
>   terminal and run the following commands (note: lines in parentheses
>   are notes, not commands - only run the commands on lines starting with
>   $, and don't include the first $, that's just notation for needing a
>   prompt):
>
> $ mkdir $HOME/wineprefix
>
> $ export WINEPREFIX=$HOME/wineprefix/ddo
>
> $ winetricks vcrun2005sp1 corefonts tahoma d3dx9    (note: d3dx9 usually
>   isn't required anymore, but doesn't hurt, and not having it can break
>   on some systems) \
>
> $ wine ddolive.exe    (follow the prompts and wait
>   for wine to for the program to finish the basic installation)    (I
>   recommend not installing shortcuts - a desktop shortcut will still be
>   created for you)
>
> $ wineboot    (I don't know if this is always
>   required, but it's not a bad idea.)
>
> Once the installation completes, double-click the ddo icon on your
>   desktop (note: don't close your terminal just yet, you might need it).
>
> Now is the tricky part: The launcher should try to install Akamai
>   Netsession. If the launcher hangs without ever displaying Turbine's
>   version of the Akamai Netsession license agreement, close it, go back
>   to your terminal and run the following command:
>
> $ ps aux | grep netsession
>
> This will show 0 to 3 lines, depending on whether grep shows itself on
>   your system and whether netsession is currently running.  If there are
>   2 or more lines, the 2 lines we're worried about are the ones that say
>   "netsession_win.exe".  The second column in each line is a number. 
>   Run the following command for each line, replacing $NUMBER with the
>   numbers you found, one at a time, starting with the one that does not
>   say "--client" (note: pkill doesn't work here or I'd have suggested
>   it):
>
> $ kill -9 $NUMBER
>
> Once you've done that, or if grep didn't say anything about netsession
>   (ie grep only returned 1 line, or nothing at all), do the following:
>
> $ export WINEPREFIX=$HOME/wineprefix/ddo    (only needed if you've
>   closed the terminal since you started the install) $ wineboot
>
> Now try running the launcher again.  Eventually, the launcher should
>   pop up a license agreement, and then it may pop itself back up over
>   the top of the agreement.  If it does, alt-tab back to the agreement,
>   then scroll down and click accept to begin installing Netsession. 
>   Follow the prompts, including accepting the agreement again, and once
>   Netsession is installed, the launcher should begin downloading DDO.
>
> Once the installer finishes downloading everything, the game should be
>   ready to play, enjoy. :)
>
> PlayOnLinux users:
>
> Start PlayOnLinux as usual.
>   If this is your first time using PlayOnLinux (or you've always just used "system" wine), you'll need to install at least one version
>   of wine in PlayOnLinux - here's how:
>           Go to Tools->Manage Wine Versions
>           In the "available versions" side of the dialog, select any version that ends in a number (i.e. 1.7.22, not 1.7.21-swtor, for
>   example - I recommend either the highest version that ends in a
>   number, or 1.6.2), and click the ">" button.
>           Close the "Manage Wine Versions" window and continue.
>       Click install (the big "+" button).
>       In the lower-left corner of the window that appears, click "Install a non-listed program".
>       Click next, select "install a program in a new virtual drive", and click next again.
>       Enter a name for your virtual drive.  I used "ddo".
>       In the next dialog, check the boxes for "use another version" and "install libraries" (paraphrazed).
>       Next, PlayOnLinux will ask you to choose a wine version.  Choose any version that ends in a number - I recommend either 1.6.2 or the
>   latest version (currently 1.7.22, but this changes a lot).  If no wine
>   versions other than "System" and versions that end in something other
>   than a number are listed, cancel the instal and follow the
>   instructions above for installing a wine version - both System and
>   "named" wine versions can cause problems with DDO (named moreso than
>   system, but both tend to cause their share of problems).
>       After you click "next", wine PlayOnLinux will create your Virtual Drive, then run winecfg. In winecfg, go to Graphics, click "Emulate a
>   Virtual Desktop" and in the 2 boxes that just became active, enter
>   your desktop resolution (if you want to play in windowed mode, either
>   just click OK or enter the resolution you want to play at) and click
>   OK.
>       Now PlayOnLinux will show you a bunch of things you can install in your wineprefix.  You need to check the following 4 items from this
>   list:
>           POL_Install_corefonts
>           POL_Install_d3dx9
>           POL_Install_tahoma
>           POL_Install_vcrun2005
>       After selecting the above, click next.
>       After a few seconds, PlayOnLinux will prompt you to select the installer to run.  Click browse, find "ddolive.exe", and once you've
>   selected it click next.
>       Go through the install wizard, selecting all the defaults, until it finishes.  When it's done, PlayOnLinux will pop up a list of exes
>   to install shortcuts for.  Select "TurbineLauncher.exe" and click
>   next, name the launcher anything you want (I named mine "DDO"), click
>   next again, then select "I don't want to make another shortcut" and
>   click next one more time.
>       The PlayOnLinux installer will then close.  Select your DDO shortcut in the POL window, click "configure", click the "Wine" tab,
>   and click "Windows Reboot", then close the configure window.
>       Your next step is to simply run the launcher, so select it in the list of games and click on the "run" button.  The Launcher should
>   start, and then bring up a license agreement - if it doesn't, close
>   the launcher, run whatever task manager you like or open a terminal,
>   and kill any running instances of "netsession_win.exe", and then
>   restart the launcher.
>       After the license agreement pops up, the launcher may pop back up to the top, covering up the agreement - if this happens just alt-tab
>   back to the license agreement.  Read that (or just scroll through it
>   to the bottom) and click "Accept".  This will start the Akamai
>   Netsession installer.  Follow the prompts, accpeting the agreement
>   again, and let it install.  Once installed, the launcher should start
>   downloading DDO.  When it finishes, you should be able to log in. 
>   Have fun. :)
>
> Fixes
>
> At this point you should be able to sign in and play the game. But its
>   normal for some issues to arise. Here are some tweaks/fixes you can
>   try.
>
> “AwsomiumProcess has encountered…”
>
> If you followed the instructions above when installing you shouldn't
>   run into this one, but if you do....
>
> This error is common among the Wine games. Seems to pertain to the
>   fonts somehow. In many cases the error can be closed & ignored. The
>   game continues to work fine. But it doesn’t stop once it starts. The
>   fix is to run:
>
> $ winetricks corefonts tahoma
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
>
> This problem (if it occurs) happens to kick in when you try to switch
>   to windowed mode or change video resolutions. In my case on Manjaro
>   the solution was to install the ‘pulseaudio-alsa’ package and reboot
>   my system.  (Note:  This issue is probably specific to arch and gentoo
>   (and derivatives, like manjaro and funtoo). For gentoo users who use
>   PulseAudio, if you run into this issue, make sure PA is built with
>   USE="alsa" and if not rebuild it with the alsa useflag enabled - and a
>   word to the wise:  only set USE="-alsa" for those programs that
>   support pulseaudio and have an "alsa" useflag - setting USE="-alsa"
>   globally can cause problems, like no sound in some apps).
>
> Set the correct video memory size in the Registry.
>
> Wine doesn’t usually input your video memory size correctly. To take
>   advantage of your video memory you can set the amount yourself with
>   winetricks.
>
> 1gb = 1024 (change to your video memory size).
>
> Note:  winetricks only suports video memory sizes of 512M, 1024M (1G),
>   and 2048M (2G).  If your card doesn't have one of those memory sizes
>   (i.e. 128M, 256M, 768M,  1536M/1.5G, or >2048M/2G), you'll have to set
>   this by hand. See http://wiki.winehq.org/UsefulRegistryKeys for how to
>   do this.
>
> $ winetricks videomemorysize=1024
>
> Set Direct Draw Renderer to OpenGL
>
> Setting this option can improve the game performance. Or at least it
>   seems to work in my case.
>
> $ winetricks ddr=opengl
>
> (note: this should be the default, but just to be sure...)
>
> Set OffscreenRenderingMode to pbuffer
>
> Open regedit with:
>
> $ wine regedit
>
> Fine the key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\Direct3D
>
> And a new string value named ‘OffscreenRenderingMode’ and set it to
>   ‘pbuffer’
>
> Install PhysX (Nvidia only)
>
> Nvidia users can improve the performance of game physics by installing
>   PhysX from Nvidia. Winetricks can handle this.
>
> $ winetricks physx
>
> Note: This requires the nVidia OpenCL drivers to be installed,
>   including the 32-bit ones for your system.  If they're not installed,
>   DDO will crash with PhysX installed, so be sure to have them
>   installed.
>
> ```
>  Game Tweaks
> ```
>
> Game Tweaks
>
> Tweaking the game:
>
> Setting the video memory size usually fixes most performance issues.
>   However there is a list of things you can do to try to kick the
>   performance up an extra notch. Of course these are just suggestions.
>   They are all optional.
>
> Disable desktop 3D effects (In Unity switch to 2D session)
>
> The 3D desktop features can cause some performance issues in the game.
>   Logging out and changing your Unity session, or disabling 3D desktop
>   effects can greatly increase game performance.
>
> Choose a ‘Graphics Quality’ in Options->Graphics
>
> It’s common for the auto detection to misdetect the card since there
>   is a wine api in the middle of everything. Select this manually to get
>   the quality you want. (I chose ‘very high’ for my 1gb Nvidia card)
>
> Increase ‘Texture Cache Size’ in Options->Adv. Graphics
>
> You can increase this to improve the game performance by increasing
>   the amount of system memory used for graphics resources. This can
>   decrease load times and in turn increase game performance.
>
> Enable ‘Triple Buffering’ in Options->Adv. Graphics
>
> For video cards with extra memory you can use this setting to slightly
>   increase rendering performance.
>
> Disable ‘Player Mesh Combining’ in Options->Adv. Graphics
>
> This feature not only uses up more system memory, but also video
>   memory. Saving a little video memory can always help game performance.
>
> Disable ‘Distant Imposters’ in Options->Adv. Graphics
>
> This option simply allows trees and other objects to render over
>   distant scenery. Can be disabled to increase game performance.
>
> If you use the Turbine Launcher, and don't have the game installed on
>   an SSD, enable preloading of game files (or client_gamelogic.dat?) in
>   the launcher's options.
>
> This preloads the client_gamelogic.dat file into memory, drastically
>   decreasing initial login/load time, at the cost of needing about 300M
>   of extra memory when launching the game (this is a fix/workaround for
>   the first-login red-latency-disconnect bug).

Comment: DDO is indeed the popular Acronym for the D&D MMO.